# DocuSign: Edit fields in a pre-filled PDF #DocuSignAPI

Tags: docusignapi

We have a system that creates pre-filled PDF contracts that we then need to send to the customer for signature and also allow the customer to update fields that may contain erroneous information.

I have reviewed the API extensively and understand that I can use text tabs placed on the document to allow customer to edit those fields. However this approach is not replacing the value already on the PDF, rather writing over it. See attached screenshot of sample document: [DocuSign Overwrite text field](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5NgEieXdE8JN0twRUtnUWltczg/view?usp=sharing)

What is the alternative or any tips on how to get around this issue will be highly appreciated.

Here is one workaround or option but I hope there is a better way

1) Instead of using the templating engine that generates this PDF, move this burden to Docusign. We can then use the text tabs within Docusign to pre-populate fields and leave it editable.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a PDF with form fields DocuSign can convert those PDF form fields into DocuSign data tabs which I believe is the workaround you've mentioned.  This is definitely the easiest approach and should work.

You can do a quick manual test by uploading a document into the DocuSign console (ie login to your account through the website) and if you feed it a PDF with form fields the system will ask if you'd like to convert them to DocuSign tabs.  To achieve this through the API you can use the `transformPdfFields` property in the document object.